# OpenCL Texture/surface reference must be simple name

Tags: opencl

I'm getting the following error when compiling my kernel:

```
    Error: (0): Texture/surface reference must be simple name
```

I reduced it down as much as possible to the following example kernel, which demonstrates the problem:

```
__kernel void accum(__global __read_only image2d_t accumulateds) {
    int2 pos = (int2)(get_global_id(0),get_global_id(1));
    float4 accum = read_imagef(accumulateds,CLK_RGBA|CLK_ADDRESS_CLAMP|CLK_FILTER_NEAREST,pos);
}
```

I found some unhelpful [forum](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=219048). [posts](http://www.facepunch.com/threads/1167392/25)., but otherwise no mention of this error whatsoever.  Additionally, I have seen example code that looks similar to the above example.  My GPU (GeForce 580M GTX) should support reading images (it supports writing, for one thing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much deliberation, I have found the cause.  My guess is that read_imagef is a macro that can't understand | instructions, so they hardcoded a preprocessor check against it.  Apparently, this issue is specific to NVIDIA hardware (or maybe my particular implementation), because code written the first way works for other people.

Method 1 (fails):

```
float4 my_value = read_imagef(my_image,CLK_FILTER_NEAREST|CLK_ADDRESS_CLAMP,my_position);
```

Method 2 (works):

```
sampler_t my_sampler = CLK_FILTER_NEAREST|CLK_ADDRESS_CLAMP;
float4 my_value = read_imagef(my_image,my_sampler,my_position);
```

As an additional note, in my original code I |ed in CLK_RGBA.  This is incorrect, and will cause an error.  It must be one of the fields [here](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/sampler_t.html).